# Set up Confluent Metrics Reporter at wurstmeister/kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-control-center

Control-Center with wurstmeister/kafka at docker.

But when I open cp-control-center I can't see the metrics for broker. There is a report message that says *Set up Confluent Metrics Reporter* .

Can I do set up and take the metrics for wurstmeister/kafka image?

My docker-compose file is the following

```
kafka:
    image: wurstmeister/kafka
    container_name: kafka
    hostname: kafka
    ports:
      - "9092"
      - "9999"
    environment:
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME: kafka
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_PORT: 9092
      KAFKA_PORT: 9092
      KAFKA_JMX_OPTS: "-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote=true -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.local.only=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=kafka -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.rmi.port=9999"
      JMX_PORT: 9999
      KAFKA_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://:9092
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://172.22.0.4:9092
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
    
  control-center:
    image: confluentinc/cp-enterprise-control-center:6.0.0
    hostname: control-center
    container_name: control-center
    depends_on:
      - kafka
    ports:
      - "9021:9021"
    environment:
      CONTROL_CENTER_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: kafka:9092
      CONTROL_CENTER_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      CONTROL_CENTER_INTERNAL_TOPICS_PARTITIONS: 1
      CONTROL_CENTER_MONITORING_INTERCEPTOR_TOPIC_PARTITIONS: 1
      CONFLUENT_METRICS_TOPIC_REPLICATION: 1
      PORT: 9021
```

Answer (score 0):

The metrics reporters for the brokers aren't on the classpath for the wurstmeister container and the metrics topic isn't created.

You'd have to [download the Confluent Platform to get those reporters](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66855305/2308683), so no reason not to use their container

Comment: I use an open source application that use wurstmeister container and I can't change that because after I have to change the code of the application. I just want to take the metrics for consumer. But also using JMX I have to make changes in the application. So is there any way to take the metrics for consumer without change the application code?

Comment: The Confluent image is also open source, and nothing related to code needs to change to use a Kafka address at the same location. As mentioned, you'll have to somehow download and add the metrics reporter JARS into the application's and container's classpaths

Comment: Alternatively, plenty of people use Prometheus and Grafana instead of control center