# How to connect Apache kafka metrices in confluent control center?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform, confluent-control-center

we are using apache kafka 2.7 version, Before that we used confluent-platform version of kafka where we can access control center to view the statistics like incoming/outgoing data rate,disk space like those metrices.

Now we are using apache kafka and need to view the same kind of statistics in control center

is it possible..?

if possible can anyone tell how to perform these?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd need to download Confluent Platform, still, then find and copy all relevant JAR files for the Confluent interceptors and metric reporters into the Kafka libs directory in each broker (and other clients like Connect), then reconfigure the relevant properties and restart each system. You might also be able to grab the jar(s) [directly from Maven](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.confluent/confluent-metrics)

Note that Apache Kafka brokers will not detect any broker configuration that starts with `confluent.` prefix, so you'll also need to manually create some topics like `_confluent-metrics`

https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/kafka/metrics-reporter.html

Comment: Thanks @OneCricketeer ,it is worked and i can able see the  metrices clearly,  Thank you so much..